# Gettin a value from a table and using in the same query

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT (h.horario), h.codigo
FROM horarios as h
JOIN horario_turma as h_t
ON(h.codigo != h_t.cd_horario)
WHERE h_t.cd_turma = 'HTJ009' 
AND h_t.cd_dia = 2
AND h.cd_turno = 1
```

I'm trying to figure out if there's a possibility to get the `h.cd_turno`value from another table and use in the same query, beacuse this value is gonna be variable. So, I'd have to get this value from a query, then pass the value to PHP and do another query with this value. Is there a way to do that in the same query?

There's a table called `turmas(codigo, cd_turno)`. I'll have the `codigo`value, in this case `HTJ009`, and I'd like to select the `cd_turno` value.

Query used to get the value:

```
SELECT cd_turno FROM turmas WHERE codigo='HTJ009'
```

Comment: Can you show the query that you use to get the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a subquery, like so:

```
SELECT (h.horario), h.codigo
FROM horarios as h
JOIN horario_turma as h_t
ON(h.codigo != h_t.cd_horario)
WHERE h_t.cd_turma = 'HTJ009' 
AND h_t.cd_dia = 2
AND h.cd_turno = (SELECT cd_turno FROM turmas WHERE codigo='HTJ009')
```

In this case, remember that it is important for the subquery to return only one result, otherwise you'll encounter an error. If you do see such an error, you may have to tweak the subquery to ensure only one result is returned.

Check this out for [Postgres subquery documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-subquery.html)

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Yes, I'm sure it'll return just one result, because turmas.codigo is a PK. I didn't know how to use the subqueries. Can I do like that multiple times? Like `AND h.cd_turno = (SELECT cd_turno FROM turmas WHERE codigo=(SELECT ...))` ?

Comment: @user3260711 Yep, you can have as many subqueries as needed (to a point). There does come a point where you'll probably impact performance negatively, and I believe there is a technical limit on number of subqueries in a single statement, but its doubtful you'll ever hit that unless you go nuts. Also too, you may find sometimes that a query is better served by a `JOIN` or some such filter rather than a subquery (generally speaking, all depends on the situation).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (h.horario), h.codigo
FROM horarios as h
JOIN horario_turma as h_t
ON(h.codigo = h_t.cd_horario)
WHERE h_t.cd_turma = 'HTJ009' 
AND h_t.cd_dia = 2
AND h.cd_turno = 1 and h_t.cd_horario is null
```